# I am looking for a way to have a search index find specific files in my database and open them

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a growing database of clients that I use for tracking in my business. Each folder has the same files in them with the contents of the files being the tracking data of each client. I was hoping to create a search index to search for a specific client and open 2 specific files in the client folder.

Example:
client folders are based off of first and last names: client "John Smith" would have a folder titled "SmiJoh"

the 2 files I would like to open in his(or any other client's) folder are "satiSOAP.xlsx" and "problemtracker.xlsm"

Clicking through the folders searching by eye is just getting too time consuming.

Thank you for any help!

I have used some basic VBA stuff in excel before but I am no where near to the ability to create something like this on my own.